# Associating .csv arrival delay time values to a key that represents a flight company.

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm working on an airport project.

I have a file with airline codes, destination airports and arrival delays.

I'm trying to generate a dictionary where the key is the airline code and the value is a list with the arrival delays of that airline.

Here's my current code:

```
def collects_statistics(statistics):
flights = []
flights_with_time = OrderedDict()
with open(statistics, 'rU') as file1:
    reader1 = csv.DictReader(file1)
    for flight in file1:
        if flight['AIRLINE_ID'] not in flights_with_time:
            flights_with_time[flight['AIRLINE_ID']] = []
# Don't know what to do next.
# Want to put the delays of each airline in the flights_with_time[flight['AIRLINE_ID']]

return voos_com_tempo
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q1Ns.png

This is the file I told you guys about.

For example, for flight with airline code 19393 I want [all arrival delays from 19393], for flight with airline code 19690 I want [all arrival delays from 19690], so on, so forth.

I'm really struggling to make this happen. The idea is well defined in my head, just can't put into practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your 90% of the way there you just need to append to the list now:

```
    def collects_statistics(statistics):
        flights = []
        flights_with_time = OrderedDict()
        with open(statistics, 'rU') as file1:
            reader1 = csv.DictReader(file1)
            for flight in file1:
            if flight['AIRLINE_ID'] not in flights_with_time:
                flights_with_time[flight['AIRLINE_ID']] = []

            #add the flight delay to the list
            flights_with_time[flight['AIRLINE_ID']].append(flight['ARR_DELAY_NEW'])

        return flights_with_time
```

Comment: Could I send you my .csv file?

This is taking forever to return a value because the .csv holds 412,000 lines!

Answer (score 0):

If the Flight id already exists as a dictioary key, you need to append the delay time in the list which would be in the value of that flight id key... This comes to my mind.

```
def collects_statistics(statistics):
    flights = []
    flights_with_time = OrderedDict()
    with open(statistics, 'rU') as file1:
        reader1 = csv.DictReader(file1)
        for flight in file1:
            if flight['AIRLINE_ID'] not in flights_with_time:
                flights_with_time[flight['AIRLINE_ID']] = []
            else:
                flights_with_time[flight['AIRLINE_ID']].append(flight['ARR_DELAY_NEW'])
```

Comment: Hi!

First things first, thanks for the help.

Thing is, my .csv holds 412,000 lines and thus, it takes forever to return a value. How can I make this go faster?

Answer (score 0):

Use SetDefault, it's an easy way of doing it.

```
def collects_statistics(statistics):
    flights_with_time = OrderedDict()
    with open(statistics, 'rU') as file1:
        reader1 = csv.DictReader(file1)
        for flight in file1:
            AIPORT_CODE = flight['AIRLINE_ID']
            flights_with_time.setdefault(AIPORT_CODE, []).append(flight['ARR_DELAY_NEW'])

    return flights_with_time
```